# how to use both scriptmanger and ajaxtoolscript manager in one single aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.5

I tried to use update panel in aspx page to avoid page refresh after button click event but in my code I used Ajax rating control for that i used asp:ToolkitScriptManager but for update panel I added scriptmanager its showing error "only one instance of a scriptmanager can be added to the page".without ajaxtoolkit rating wont work.Please can anyone suggest me how to overcome from this problem and how to avoid page refresh after buttonclick.
my code:
kgis.aspx

```
           <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
           <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
               <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:HiddenField ID="currTab" runat="server" />
       <asp:Panel ID="tabPanel" runat="server">
        <ul>
             <li><a href="#Panel1" style="padding-left:8px;"><span>General Feedback</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#Panel2" style="padding-left:6px;"><span>New Requirements</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#Panel3" style="padding-left:8px;"><span>My Feedback</span></a></li>

        </ul>

        <%-- general feedback tab--%>

   <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">

          <div class="tabcaption">General Feedback</div>

         <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
            <table class="general">
                                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:22px;">1.Did you find the information you were looking for?</td>
                                    </tr>
                                     <tr>
                     <td style="padding-left:30px;">  if no please explain why?</td>

                    </tr>
                      <tr >
                   <td style="padding-left:28px;">
                        <div id="RadioDiv1">
               <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radiolist1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" CssClass="radio1">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="yes">Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="no">No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                     </div>
               </td>
               </tr>

                <tr >

                    <td >
                        <div id="info" style="padding-left:64px;">Please Explain:
                          <asp:TextBox ID="infodesc" runat="server" CssClass="textb" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                     <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:22px;"> 2.Did the portal meet your need/ answer your questions?</td>
                             </tr>
                                     <tr>
                     <td style="padding-left:30px;">  if no please explain why?</td>

                    </tr>
                      <tr >
                   <td style="padding-left:28px;">
                        <div id="RadioDiv2">
               <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" CssClass="radio1">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="yes">Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="no">No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                     </div>
               </td>
               </tr>
                <tr >

                    <td >
                        <div id="port" style="padding-left:64px;">Please Explain:
                          <asp:TextBox ID="portdesc" runat="server" CssClass="textb" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr><td style="padding-left:22px;">3.Please rate these</td> 

                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:32px;">a.GUI</td>

                    <td>

                      <asp:Rating ID="Rating1" runat="server" BehaviorID="RatingBehavior1" CssClass="textb"
                                MaxRating="5"
                                StarCssClass="ratingStar"
                                WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar1"
                                FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar1"
                                EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar1"
                                OnChanged="ThaiRating_Changed"
                                Style="float: left;" />

                    </td>


                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:32px;">b.Correctness of content</td>

                    <td>

                      <asp:Rating ID="Rating2" runat="server" BehaviorID="RatingBehavior2" CssClass="textb"
                                MaxRating="5"
                                StarCssClass="ratingStar"
                                WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar1"
                                FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar1"
                                EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar1"
                                OnChanged="ThaiRating_Changed"
                                Style="float: left;" />

                    </td>


                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:32px;">c.Existing functionality</td>

                    <td>

                      <asp:Rating ID="Rating3" runat="server" BehaviorID="RatingBehavior3" CssClass="textb"
                                MaxRating="5"
                                StarCssClass="ratingStar"
                                WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar1"
                                FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar1"
                                EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar1"
                                OnChanged="ThaiRating_Changed"
                                Style="float: left;" />

                    </td>


                </tr>


                <tr><td style="padding-left:22px;">4.Please give a feedback</td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:34px;">
                         <asp:TextBox ID="msg" runat="server" CssClass="textb" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:22px;">5.Do you have any document/image/screenshot/slide for the new requirement reference? if yes,please upload(max 2MB)</td>
                   </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                         <asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload1" runat="server" CssClass="textb" onchange="validateFileSize();"/>

                         <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" Text="&nbsp;" runat="server" style="color:Red;"/>
                         <div id="dvMsg" style="color:Red; width:195px;display:none;" >
              File size is greater than 2mb </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" Text="Save and Continue" CssClass="btn" AutoPostback = "false"/>
      <%--  <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Save and Continue" CssClass="btn" OnClick="Button4_Click" />--%>
      </asp:Panel>






        <%-- new requirements tab--%>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
            <div class="tabcaption">New requirements</div>

           <table class="newrq">

                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:22px;"> 1.What are your new Requirements? Please Explain: </td>
                    </tr>
                      <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:53px;">

                       <asp:TextBox ID="newrequire" runat="server" CssClass="textb" TextMode="MultiLine" ></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>

                      </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  style="padding-left:22px;">2.Do you require any new functions ?</td>
                      </tr>
               <tr >
                   <td style="padding-left:28px;">
                        <div id="RadioDiv">
               <asp:RadioButtonList ID="newfunc" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" CssClass="radio1">

                            <asp:ListItem Value="yes">Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="no">No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                     </div>
               </td>
               </tr>

               <tr >
                  <%-- <td style="padding-left:28px;width:200px;margin-left:-220px;">Functions List</td>--%>
                    <td>
                        <div id="fundiv" style="padding-left:64px;"> 
                          Functions List:
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="funlist" runat="server">
                              <asp:ListItem runat="server" Value="no">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem runat="server"  Value="yes">Reports</asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem runat="server" Value="yes">Charts</asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem runat="server" Value="yes">Graphs</asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem runat="server" Value="yes">Analysis</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem runat="server" Value="yes">Others</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                      </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
               <tr><%-- <td style="padding-left:28px;width:200px;margin-left:-220px;">Please Explain</td>--%>
                   <td>
                       <div id="expdiv" style="padding-left:64px;">
                           Please Explain:
                           <asp:TextBox ID="fundesc" runat="server" CssClass="textb" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                           <a alt="Reports" class="tooltipDemo" href="#">
                           <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" Height="25px" ImageUrl="images/tooltip.jpg" style="margin-top: -49px;" Width="25px" />
                           </a>
                       </div>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:22px;">3.What will be the input data for the requirement?</td>
                     </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td style="width:385px;padding-left:53px;">

                         <asp:TextBox ID="inpt" runat="server" CssClass="textb" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:22px;">4.What should be the output data for the requirement?</td>
                     </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td style="width:385px;padding-left:53px;">

                         <asp:TextBox ID="oupt" runat="server" CssClass="textb" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:22px;">5.Do you have any document/image/screenshot/slide for the new requirement reference? if yes,please upload(max 2MB)</td>
                   </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                         <asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload2" runat="server" CssClass="textb" onchange="validateFileSize1();"/>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>

                  <div id="dvMsg1" style="color:Red; width:195px;display:none;" >
              File size is greater than 2mb </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

             </table>

            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="btnUpload_Click1" CssClass="btn" />

        </asp:Panel>


        <%-- My feedback  tab--%>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server">

             <div class="tabcaption">  </div>
          <div style="overflow:auto;">General Feedback
             <asp:GridView ID="dataGridView2" runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
        AutoGenerateColumns="true" OnPageIndexChanging="datagrid_PageIndexChangingimg">


             </asp:GridView></div>
            <br /><br />
               <div style="overflow:auto;">
            New Requirements
               <asp:GridView ID="dataGridView3" runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
AutoGenerateColumns="true" OnPageIndexChanging="datagrid_PageIndexChangingimg1">

               </asp:GridView></div>


        </asp:Panel>

    </asp:Panel>
                   </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" /> 
      </Triggers>
               </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
```

kgis.aspx.cs

protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        MimeType m = new MimeType();
        HttpPostedFile file = fileupload1.PostedFile;
        byte[] document = new byte[file.ContentLength];
        file.InputStream.Read(document, 0, file.ContentLength);
        string s = m.GetMimeType(document, file.ToString());


        switch (Rating1.CurrentRating)
        {
            case 1:
                remarks = "Poor";
                break;
            case 2:
                remarks = "Average";
                break;
            case 3:
                remarks = "Good";
                break;
            case 4:
                remarks = "Very Good";
                break;
            case 5:
                remarks = "Excellent";
                break;
        }

        switch (Rating2.CurrentRating)
        {
            case 1:
                remarks = "Poor";
                break;
            case 2:
                remarks = "Average";
                break;
            case 3:
                remarks = "Good";
                break;
            case 4:
                remarks = "Very Good";
                break;
            case 5:
                remarks = "Excellent";
                break;
        }
        //string remarks2 = "[unknown]";
        switch (Rating3.CurrentRating)
        {
            case 1:
                remarks = "Poor";
                break;
            case 2:
                remarks = "Average";
                break;
            case 3:
                remarks = "Good";
                break;
            case 4:
                remarks = "Very Good";
                break;
            case 5:
                remarks = "Excellent";
                break;
        }


        if (s.Equals("not valid file"))
        {

           // ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('file is not valid')", true);
            //Console.WriteLine("The variable is set to true.");
            Label1.Text = "file is not valid";
        }

        else
        {

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {



                        con.Open();
                        cmd.CommandText = "insert into FileInformation(usernm,emailID,info,infodesc,portal,portdesc,guirating,ccrating,efrating,feedback,FileName,FileType,FileData) values(@usernm,@emailID,@info,@infodesc,@portal,@portdesc,@guirating,@ccrating,@efrating,@feedback,@Name,@Type,@Data)";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usernm", usernm);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailID", emailID);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@info", radiolist1.SelectedItem.Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@infodesc", infodesc.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@portal", RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@portdesc", portdesc.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guirating", remarks);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccrating", remarks);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@efrating", remarks);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@feedback", msg.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", file.FileName);

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", s);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", document);


                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                        // BindGridviewData();

                        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "javascript:alert('feedback recieved successfully')", true);



                }
            }
        }

         radiolist1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        infodesc.Text = "";
        RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        portdesc.Text = "";
        msg.Text = "";
        Rating1.CurrentRating = 0;
        Rating2.CurrentRating = 0;
        Rating3.CurrentRating = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

Proof:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/using-both-ajaxtoolkit-scriptmanager-and-telerikscriptmanager

An answer from Telerik team says,

> "Using both script mangers (RadScriptManager and ToolkitScriptManager) is not supported since you could have only one script manager control on the page. In such cases it's appropriate to use the RadScriptManager and manually register the scripts needed by the AjaxToolKit."

Comment: You are Welcome